# Nombrar hoja de previsión en VBA

Tags: vba

soy nuevo en VBA, y quisiera saber cómo asignarle un nombre específico a la hoja de proyección que he creado en VBA con el método .CreateForecastSheet, en lugar de que arroje "Hoja1", "Hoja2", como lo hace por defecto.

```
Sub Prevision()

ActiveWorkbook.CreateForecastSheet Timeline:=Sheets("PLAN DE COMPRAS").Range( _
    "B29:BA29"), Values:=Sheets("PLAN DE COMPRAS").Range("B21:BA21"), _
    ForecastStart:="5/09/2022", ForecastEnd:="26/12/2022", ConfInt:=0.95, _
    Seasonality:=1, ChartType:=xlForecastChartTypeLine, Aggregation:= _
    xlForecastAggregationAverage, DataCompletion:= _
    xlForecastDataCompletionInterpolate, ShowStatsTable:=True 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.createforecastsheet) no indica que sea posible darle nombre directamente a la creación de la hoja con las predicciones (en el método, mejor dicho).

Entonces, podrías simplemente renombrarla *manomáticamente*:

```
Sub Prevision()

  ActiveWorkbook.CreateForecastSheet Timeline:=Sheets("PLAN DE COMPRAS").Range( _
    "B29:BA29"), Values:=Sheets("PLAN DE COMPRAS").Range("B21:BA21"), _
    ForecastStart:="5/09/2022", ForecastEnd:="26/12/2022", ConfInt:=0.95, _
    Seasonality:=1, ChartType:=xlForecastChartTypeLine, Aggregation:= _
    xlForecastAggregationAverage, DataCompletion:= _
    xlForecastDataCompletionInterpolate, ShowStatsTable:=True 

  Set Sheet = Worksheets("Hoja1")
  Sheet.Name = "Renamed Sheet"

End Sub
```

Lo otro que [sí sabemos](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-forecast-in-excel-for-windows-22c500da-6da7-45e5-bfdc-60a7062329fd) es que Excel pone esa nueva hoja *a la izquierda* de la hoja  que contiene las series que se usan como insumo, entonces podrías usar el truco de seleccionar la hoja con las series y decirle que use la anterior

```
Dim wsPrevious As Worksheet

Sub Prevision()

  ActiveWorkbook.CreateForecastSheet Timeline:=Sheets("PLAN DE COMPRAS").Range( _
    "B29:BA29"), Values:=Sheets("PLAN DE COMPRAS").Range("B21:BA21"), _
    ForecastStart:="5/09/2022", ForecastEnd:="26/12/2022", ConfInt:=0.95, _
    Seasonality:=1, ChartType:=xlForecastChartTypeLine, Aggregation:= _
    xlForecastAggregationAverage, DataCompletion:= _
    xlForecastDataCompletionInterpolate, ShowStatsTable:=True 

  Worksheets("PLAN DE COMPRAS").Activate
  Set wsPrevious = ActiveSheet.Previous 
  wsPrevious.Name = "Hoja Mágica"

End Sub
```